# With pexpect, is there a simple way to get multiple events (combine it with normal I/O)?

Tags: python-3.x, select, pexpect

I'd like to expect output from my child process and at the same time, from the terminal - the one which comes first. If those were two devices, i could use the `select()` system call, but I don't know and failed to find, how to combine it with `expect()`.

Answer (score 0):

The child object has a `fileno()` method that returns the file object suitable for select.

```py
child = pexpect.spawn(...)
rlist = [child.fileno()]
(rlist, wlist, xlist) = select.select(rlist, [], [])
```